# Benefits of UNIX or UNIX variant on microcontroller?

Tags: linux, arduino, microcontroller, beagleboneblack

This may be a foolish question but I've been searching around for some time and don't see a clear answer. I've seen several microcontrollers advertised as running Unix-like software (Linux, Ubuntu) for example, the BeagleBone Black and Arduino Yun. Can someone please explain to me the benefit of this? So far I've used a couple of microcontrollers like the Arduino Uno/Duo, Freescale FRDM and STM32 Discovery which either didn't have this feature or I was not aware of it. I'm starting to see it more and more on newer microcontrollers so I'd like to know what it brings to the table.

Full disclosure: I've had minimal exposure to UNIX and its variants so far so please talk slowly and use small words =)

Hope to hear from you, 
Yusif Nurizade

Comment: Those are not microcontrollers running linux that you pointed out.  They may or may not have other chips on board that may be or have microcontrollers in them but the processors running linux are not.

Comment: dwelch, you are right, thank you for the correction. I am beginning to understand the role UNIX variants play in embedded systems and will be looking into it more in depth.

Comment: Linux/Unix will give you a desktop application like interface for programs, takes a lot more power and money but doesnt require special programming skills.  For pennies per unit type stuff you still have microcontrollers and those have environments to make life easier but the systems are considerably more restricted than embedded unix systems.  A set top box like a roku, embedded linux make sense, worth the power and cost, the remote control that runs that roku, a microcontroller makes sense.

Comment: the raspberry pi and beaglebone black and others are demonstrating that for some number of dollars for an eval board you can get linux and maybe throw in a microcontroller or few for fun, but an eval board or homebrew board is one thing, when you turn it into a product even $25 vs $0.25 makes a big difference, batteries that are drained in seconds vs days, etc.

Comment: dwelch, thank you for the elaboration. Could you please clarify which of these options is easier to implement? You mention the Linux/Unix option doesn't require special programming skills but also that the microcontrollers have environments that make life easier but are more restricted than the Unix/Linux option. Below Mahendra mentions the Unix/Linux option has a steep learning curve so I am a bit confused about how easy it is to break into using it.

Comment: you already said you have used the stm32 discovery and the arduino, how was your experience there compared to writing a command line or gui application on an operating system like windows or linux?

Comment: Using a C compiler for a microcontroller can have its costs as well, depends on the compiler and microcontroller, can perhaps sometimes choose a controller with half the flash or ram if you write in asm instead of C, but then there is the development and maintenance cost of using asm vs C.

Comment: which is easier, better, etc, that is all in the eye of the beholder, your answer may be different than mine which may be different than the next person, and all may be the right answer.

Comment: I suppose there is nothing to do but give it a try and see how it compares. Thanks again for the advice!

Comment: as far as linux goes you can of course just run it on a computer or virtual machine (virtualbox, etc).  There are some embedded boards that have some level of simulation in qemu as well, basically you can try this for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get complex drivers already included Linux for free (USB, internet protocols, storage media and file systems).

You can use lots of free software for the things not included in the kernel.

It is simpler to develop software on a full OS (easier to debug, look what is going on, change the configuration, etc etc).

The drawback is that the real-time capabilities are generally worse than for some small RTOS, and it needs more resources (a couple of megabytes memory).

Comment: Thank you for your response starblue. Would you say this option is for a more experienced user? I used CodeWarrior for the FRDM board, for example, and while it gives you a lot more control and debugging capability than an Arduino, the code was much more involved and took some time to get used to.

Answer (score 2):

In the heart of all Android and iphone is a Embedded Linux System. Without getting too deep

- Linux + Java = **Android**
- BSD Unix variant + C/C++/Object C = **iOS**

Now if you get deeper the above two statement can be argued for accuracy

All Android devices run on ARM based microprocessors. Beaglebone is one such open source hardware platform with can run Android as well as Embedded Linux distribution and even a Ubuntu.

Now (IMHO) Ubuntu is primarily for desktop and server application. Many of the popular computer server farms uses Ubuntu.

Now STM32 is a ARM based CORTEX-M micro control. Once again (IMHO) is mostly used for bare metal embedded applications. I have hard that FreeRTOS can be ported to TM4C123 ARM Cortex-M TM4C123.

Now the advantages of using Linux base micro controller  architecture are

1. OS is free for the most part
2. Larger community of users
3. The industry is moving towards open source
4. Lot of free resources get up to speed

Disadvantage are

1. Learning curve is pretty steep
2. Expect to stumble and fall a few time

Below to two good resources to learn Beaglebone open source development

1. [Beaglebone](http://beagleboard.org/)
2. [Introduction to Beaglebone development by Derek Molloy of Dublin City University](http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/)

HTH and good luck

Comment: Mahendra, thank you; that was very in depth! I think I understand the benefit of using a UNIX variant as an OS. As I addressed with starblue, I was worried about the learning curve associated with this feature. It definitely bears looking into for future application but due to the steep learning curve I don't imagine I will be using it now.

Comment: Note that Cortex-M has no MMU.  So you can only use ucLinux, which has some limitations (mostly fixed memory layout).